# I fill in all the values on my form and my PHP still returns Undefined Index

Tags: php, html, forms, xampp

I starting to learn PHP and I open my website up in localhost (I am using xampp) I get an undefined index error for every input tag, however, when using the website I make sure to fill everything in so that there is no missing value. Why does it still produce an Undefined Index Error? I've looked through other questions and tried repeating their code but it stil doesn't work.

```
<form id="myForm" action="test.php">
            <div id="Level1_Form"> <!--Use divs to space-->
                <div id="ContainInputDiv1-1">
                    <p class="level1InputP">First Name: <span class="formError" id="FNameErrorP"></span></p>
                    <input type="text" class="Level1InputTxt" id="fName"/>
                </div>
                <div id="ContainInputDiv1-2">
                    <p class="level1InputP">Last Name: <span class="formError" id="LNameErrorP"></span></p>
                    <input type="text" class="Level1InputTxt" id="lName"/>
                </div>
                <div id="ContainInputDiv1-3">
                    <p class="level1InputP">E-Mail: <span class="formError" id="ErrorEmailP"></span></p>
                    <input type="text" class="Level1InputTxt" id="eMail"/>
                    <p id="ErrorEMailP"></p>
                </div>
                <div id="ContainInputDiv1-4">
                    <p class="level1InputP">Phone Number: <span class="formError" id="ErrorPhoneNumP"></span></p>
                    <input type="text" class="Level1InputTxt" id="phoneNumber"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Level2_Form">
                <div id="ContainInputDiv2-1">
                    <p class="level2InputP">Street Address: <span class="formError" id="AddressErrorP"></span></p>
                    <input type="text" class="Level2InputTxt" id="address"/>
                </div>
                <div id="ContainInputDiv2-2">
                    <p class="level2InputP">Town: <span class="formError" id="TownErrorP"></span></p>
                    <input type="text" class="Level2InputTxt"  id="town"/>
                </div>
                <div id="ContainInputDiv2-3">
                    <p class="level2InputP">Zip Code:<span class="formError" id="ErrorZipP"></span> </p>
                    <input type="text" class="Level2InputTxt"  id="zip"/>
                </div>
                <div id="ContainInputDiv2-4">
                    <p class="level2InputP">State: </p> <!--Rearrange to street address, town, state, zip-->
                    <select id="State_Select" class="Select">
                      <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                      <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                      <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Level3_Form">
                <div id="ContainInputDiv3-1">
                    <p class="level3InputP">Date: </p>
                    <div style="dispay: inline;">
                        <select id="Month_Select" class="Select">
                            <option value="1">January</option>
                            <option value="2">February</option>
                            <option value="3">March</option>
                            <option value="4">April</option>
                            <option value="5">May</option>
                            <option value="6">June</option>
                            <option value="7">July</option>
                            <option value="8">August</option>
                            <option value="9">September</option>
                            <option value="10">October</option>
                            <option value="11">November</option>
                            <option value="12">December</option>
                        </select>
                        <select id="Day_Select" class="Select">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="11">11</option>
                            <option value="12">12</option>
                            <option value="13">13</option>
                            <option value="14">14</option>
                            <option value="15">15</option>
                            <option value="16">16</option>
                            <option value="17">17</option>
                            <option value="18">18</option>
                            <option value="19">19</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="21">21</option>
                            <option value="22">22</option>
                            <option value="23">23</option>
                            <option value="24">24</option>
                            <option value="25">25</option>
                            <option value="26">26</option>
                            <option value="27">27</option>
                            <option value="28">28</option>
                            <option value="29">29</option>
                            <option value="30">30</option>
                            <option value="31">31</option>
                        </select>
                        <select id="Year_Select" class="Select">
                        <option value="2017">2017</option>
                      <option value="2018">2018</option>
                      <option value="2019">2019</option>
                        <option value="2020">2020</option>
                        <option value="2021">2021</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="ContainInputDiv3-2">
                    <p class="level3InputP">Number of People: <span class="formError" id="ErrorNumOfPeopleP"></span></p>
                    <input type="text" id="NumOfPeople" value="Integer Value Only"/>
                </div>
                <div id="ContainInputDiv3-3">
                    <p class="level3InputP">Event Type: <span class="formError" id="EventTypeErrorP"></span></p>
                    <input type="text" id="eventType" value="Wedding, Family Reunion, etc..."/>
                </div>
                <div id="ContainInputDiv3-4">
                    <p class="level3InputP">Inside or Outside: </p>
                    <select id="InOrOut_Select" class="Select">
                        <option value="1">Inside</option>
                      <option value="2">Outside</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Level4_Form">
                <p class="level4InputP">Requests/Specific Details: </p>
                <center>
                <textarea id="requests" rows="5" cols="100" style="resize: none;"/></textarea>
                </center>
            </div>
            <center>
                <div id="Level5_Form">
                    <script src="C:\Users\Connor\Desktop\Coding\Rick's Bar Service\Scripts\JS\Booking_Event.js"></script>
                    <input type="submit" id="Submit_Button" onclick="process()" value="Submit"/>
                </div>
            </center>
        </form>

<?php
$path = "C:\\Users\\Connor\\Desktop\\Coding\\Rick's Bar Service\\JSON\\Request.json";

$myObj->FName = $_POST['fName'];
$myObj->LName = $_POST['lName'];
$myObj->EMail = $_POST['eMail'];
$myObj->PhoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
$myObj->State = $_POST['State_Select'];
$myObj->Town = $_POST['town'];
$myObj->Zip = $_POST['zip'];
$myObj->Address = $_POST['address'];
$myObj->Month = $_POST['Month_Select'];
$myObj->Day = $_POST['Day_Select'];
$myObj->Year = $_POST['Year_Select'];
$myObj->NumOfPeople = $_POST['NumOfPeople'];
$myObj->EventType = $_POST['eventType'];
$myObj->InOrOut = $_POST['InOrOut_Select'];
$myObj->Requests = $_POST['requests'];

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

$myfile = fopen($path, "w");
fwrite($myfile, $myJSON);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

The errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: fName in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: lName in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: eMail in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: phoneNumber in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: State_Select in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: town in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: zip in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: Month_Select in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: Day_Select in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: Year_Select in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: NumOfPeople in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: eventType in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined index: InOrOut_Select in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: requests in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 20
```

Comment: Add `method="POST"` to your `<form>` element.  The default method is `GET`.

Comment: I added method="POST" and still got the error. I also tried using GET instead of POST (I made sure to remove method="POST" from the form)and still got the same answer. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Put method="post" back. All your inputs are missing the name attribute i.e name="fName" etc for each one... The Name attribute is what creates the corresponding $_POST[] index. If you had performed a var_dump($_POST) to debug, you would find it empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ..

Change this line from

```
<form id="myForm" action="test.php">
```

to

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="test.php">
```

and do these lines from

```
<?php
$path = "C:\\Users\\Connor\\Desktop\\Coding\\Rick's Bar Service\\JSON\\Request.json";

$myObj->FName = $_POST['fName'];
$myObj->LName = $_POST['lName'];
$myObj->EMail = $_POST['eMail'];
$myObj->PhoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
$myObj->State = $_POST['State_Select'];
$myObj->Town = $_POST['town'];
$myObj->Zip = $_POST['zip'];
$myObj->Address = $_POST['address'];
$myObj->Month = $_POST['Month_Select'];
$myObj->Day = $_POST['Day_Select'];
$myObj->Year = $_POST['Year_Select'];
$myObj->NumOfPeople = $_POST['NumOfPeople'];
$myObj->EventType = $_POST['eventType'];
$myObj->InOrOut = $_POST['InOrOut_Select'];
$myObj->Requests = $_POST['requests'];

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

$myfile = fopen($path, "w");
fwrite($myfile, $myJSON);
fclose($myfile);
```

to

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

$path = "C:\\Users\\Connor\\Desktop\\Coding\\Rick's Bar Service\\JSON\\Request.json";

$myObj->FName = $_POST['fName'];
$myObj->LName = $_POST['lName'];
$myObj->EMail = $_POST['eMail'];
$myObj->PhoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
$myObj->State = $_POST['State_Select'];
$myObj->Town = $_POST['town'];
$myObj->Zip = $_POST['zip'];
$myObj->Address = $_POST['address'];
$myObj->Month = $_POST['Month_Select'];
$myObj->Day = $_POST['Day_Select'];
$myObj->Year = $_POST['Year_Select'];
$myObj->NumOfPeople = $_POST['NumOfPeople'];
$myObj->EventType = $_POST['eventType'];
$myObj->InOrOut = $_POST['InOrOut_Select'];
$myObj->Requests = $_POST['requests'];

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

$myfile = fopen($path, "w");
fwrite($myfile, $myJSON);
fclose($myfile);

}
```

Thank you .. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check first whether really data was posted ( form submitted or not ),

```
// Check if there's ANY post data at all
// whether posted data
if (!empty($_POST))
{

    // this is a way to get out of undefined index error    
    if( isset($_POST['fName']) )
    {
        $myObj->FName = $_POST['fName'];
    }else{
           // firstname doesn't exist
    } 

    if( isset($_POST['lName']) )
    {
        $myObj->LName = $_POST['lName'];
    }

    // remaining goes here

}
```

and in form

```
<form id="myForm" action="test.php" method="POST">
```